# pgadmin4 using kerberos authentication returns error "Kerberos authentication failed. Couldn't find kerberos ticket"

Tags: postgresql, kerberos

1. My environment:

- MIT Kerberos server on Red Hat 8.8
- PostgreSQL server v15.3 on Red Hat 8.8
- PostgreSQL client v15.3 on Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop

2. I have configured PostgreSQL server to use Kerberos. On my Ubuntu Desktop where PostgreSQL client is installed, I can successfully establish Kerberos connection with PostgreSQL server using psql client.
3. On Ubuntu Desktop I have installed pgadmin4 using apache2 server following instructions: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-on-ubuntu/ I can successfully login into pgadmin4 using internal pgadmin4 connection and I can establish PostgreSQL connection with PostgreSQL server that does NOT use Kerberos. I think pgadmin4 is correctly setup.
4. Now I would like to establish Kerberos authentication with pgadmin4 to PostgreSQL Kerberos configured server. I have followed official documentation: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/kerberos.html and also watched youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDg6I21kCak - I can follow and configure everything like in doc and video, but finally when I open Firefox 113 browser, type in URL: http://desktop.example.com/pgadmin4/browser/ and pgadmin4 web page loads, but in top right corner there is error message displayed: "Kerberos authentication failed. Cound't find kerberos ticket."
5. I have checked the ticket with "klist" command and ticket is there and still valid (remember I can successfully establish Kerberos connection with psql tool). Also desktop's keytab file is present in Ubuntu.
6. On Ubuntu I have checked /var/log/pgadmin/ where is an empty file. Also checked the /var/log/apache2/ folder where the only message (during connection establishing) is in access.log:

> 192.168.100.31 - - [02/Jun/2023:13:41:49 +0200] "GET /pgadmin4/browser/ HTTP/1.1" 302 930 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu;
> Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"

> 192.168.100.31 - - [02/Jun/2023:13:42:04 +0200] "GET /pgadmin4/login?next=%2Fpgadmin4%2Fbrowser%2F HTTP/1.1" 401 5435 "-"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101
> Firefox/113.0"

7. I can't see any errors in log files. I have searched the web, but can't find anything useful.

Any idea what I can look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. In my case it was browser problem.

In Ubuntu 22.04 browser Firefox is by default installed as snap package. Snap packages are *sandboxed* and are not allowed to access Linux KEYRING where Kerberos tickers are saved.

I tried to install Firefox flatpak which is also sandboxed and access to pgAdmin4 fails with exact the same error "Cound't find kerberos ticket."

SOLUTION:

1. I have downloaded non-snap version from Mozilla Firefox
   https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US
2. Change dir to downloads directory: '`cd Downloads'
3. Untar the file: `tar xvf firefox*`
4. Change dir to extracted folder: `cd firefox`
5. Run the browser: `./firefox &`
6. Typed in my pgAdmin4 server in URL: `http://desktop.example.com/pgadmin4/browser/` and pgAdmin4 logins and at the top right is displayed: `user01@EXAMPLE.COM (kerberos)`, so I have successfully logged into PostgreSQL Server using Kerberos. Problem solved.

Recap:

- Firefox/snap: ERROR: Cound't find kerberos ticket.
- Firefox/flatpak: ERROR: Cound't find kerberos ticket.
- Mozilla/Firefox tar file: Works fine